# how to keep fragment position when adding to linearlayout dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a horizontal linear layout which programmatically generated in code, now I want to add one fragment and one secondary linear layout at a same time.
Although I'd added the fragment first, it didn't show in the first position but the secondary linear layout.

what can I do to keep the fragment in the first position ?

p/s: I think the problem not in my code but the fragment not adding to parent layout as soon as transaction commit method called.
So I want to know how to keep it position until it completely create and load into parent layout

Answer (score 0):

Check the mainactivity.java in src folder and check getPageTitle() and  getItem() methods

Comment: I'm still not understand what I have to check for?

Comment: The problem not in my code but the fragment not adding to parent layout as soon as transaction commit method called.
So I want to know how to keep it position until it completely create and load into parent layout

Comment: you mean to say your fragment is being added in second layout instead of first???

Comment: I commit fragment in my main layout then I adding another layout into main layout. but my fragment always show in 2nd position of my main layout